# How to get the list of all weeks within a time period

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get the list of all weeks within a time period. I managed to create the following query:

```
select author_name, to_char((author_date)::date, 'day') AS COMMIT_DAY, COUNT(author_email) AS COMMITS_PER_DAY
from commits 
where author_email='abc@xyz.com'
group by author_name, commit_day
order by commits_per_day DESC;
```

This produces an output like:

```
"Abc"; "wednesday"; 1700
"Abc"; "friday   "; 1685
"Abc"; "thursday "; 1677
"Abc"; "tuesday  "; 1669
"Abc"; "monday   "; 1566
"Abc"; "sunday   "; 1167
"Abc"; "saturday "; 1151
```

I'm getting the total number of commits per day between the time period (over 5 years). But how can I get the unique weeks and the commits between the time period?

The table columns are:

> id | author_name | author_email | author_date (timestamp) |
>   total_lines

Comment: You'll want to play around with date intervals:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Use `date_trunc('week'` in the `group by` if your week coincides with the server's definition.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you. Can you show me it in the above query?

Comment: I meant if your desired week runs from Sunday to Saturday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either, I don't get it or you are overthinking it.
Just group by week

```
select author_name, to_char((author_date)::date, 'week') AS COMMIT_WEEK, COUNT(author_email) AS COMMITS_PER_DAY
from commits 
where author_email='abc@xyz.com'
group by author_name, commit_week
order by commits_per_day DESC;
```

if you want unique week every year, you have to also group by year:

```
select author_name, to_char((author_date)::date, 'week') AS COMMIT_WEEK, to_char((author_date)::date, 'year') AS COMMIT_YEAR, COUNT(author_email) AS COMMITS_PER_DAY
from commits 
where author_email='abc@xyz.com'
group by author_name, commit_week, commit_year
order by commits_per_day DESC;
```

Comment: I tried this. But it is not returning unique weeks. For some reason, I'm getting weeks as `1eek`, `2eek` , `3eek, `4eek, `5eek`. But there should be ore than 200 rows if it's unique weeks. But this is not the case with this query. That's what I'm wondering

Comment: When it is for more than one year, you also have to group by year. I update the answer